# Specify version of nodejs in meta-nodejs in a Yocto project

Tags: node.js, yocto

I am working with Yocto for the first time on a proof-of-concept for an embedded system. I have setup the meta-nodejs layer and can build a version of nodejs with:

`bitbake nodejs` which runs to completion:

`NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 707 tasks of which 700 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.`

However it seems to select nodejs v0.8 by default - how I see the recipies for 4.3.1 which is what I need, but where do I specify the version? Can't find docs for this!

My local.conf shows:

`IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " nodejs"`

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify `PREFERRED_VERSION_nodejs = "4.3.1"` in one of your config files (for example `local.conf`).

Here's the respective section from the documentation:

> If there are multiple versions of recipes available, this variable
>   determines which recipe should be given preference. You must always
>   suffix the variable with the PN you want to select, and you should set
>   the PV accordingly for precedence. You can use the "%" character as a
>   wildcard to match any number of characters, which can be useful when
>   specifying versions that contain long revision numbers that could
>   potentially change. Here are two examples:
>
> ```
>  PREFERRED_VERSION_python = "2.7.3"
>  PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-yocto = "3.19%"
> ```

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-PREFERRED_VERSION

Comment: Like ... how'd I not see that?! I read those docs a bunch of times!! .. thank you